# MATLAB finding sign changing point

Tags: matlab, signals

I have a signal represented by the plot below

[image]

Now, I want to find the point where this signal crosses zero, or changes sign

I have written a code to find local/global max/min points so that I can set the interval when I locate zero-crossing(sign-changing) point

But, I am having trouble finding zero-crossing point using MATLAB

My raw data is 3D array (450x450x200) where 450x450 represents the area and 200 represents time axis

Thus, when I take, for example, (200,200) point and plot, I get the graph of signal like the one shown above.

So, my question is:

- How do you find a zero-crossing (or, sign-changing) point within certain interval?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple for-loop for the y-axis data:

```
for idx = 2:lengthOfData  % or an interval
    if sign(data(idx))*sign(data(idx-1)) == -1
        disp(data(idx))    % Or whatever you want to do with the idx
    end %if
end %for
```

Or you can use find to search for a given range of conditions (data around zero) but it doesn't give certain places, for example should the data just turn around near zero.